# Prove that the moment condition fails for AR(1) process with autocorrelated error

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, proof

Consider the simple time series model: $y_t=\rho y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ where $\varepsilon_t$ is autocorrelated. This results in that the moment condition, $E[y_{t-1}\varepsilon_t]=0$, does not hold, i.e. that $E[y_{t-1}\varepsilon_t]\neq0$.

How would you show that the moment condition does not hold?

Comment: (1) your formatting has resulted in an unreadable formula.  Please fix it.  (2) What do you mean by "that result"?  The unreadable formula or that $e_t$ is autocorrelated?

Comment: @whuber, I was just about to post my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the univariate AR(1) model where the error term also follows an AR(1) process:$y_{t}=\rho y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}$

$\varepsilon_{t}=\phi\varepsilon_{t-1}+v_{t},\quad v_{t}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\:\sigma^{2}\right)$

In this case both $\varepsilon_{t}$ and $y_{t-1}$ depend upon $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ such that the moment condition, $E\left[\varepsilon_{t}y_{t-1}\right]=0$, is violated. To see this write:

$E\left[\varepsilon_{t}y_{t-1}\right]=E\left[\left(\phi\varepsilon_{t-1}+v_{t}\right)\left(\rho y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}\right)\right]$

$E\left[\varepsilon_{t}y_{t-1}\right]=\phi\rho E\left[\varepsilon_{t-1}y_{t-2}\right]+\phi E\left[\varepsilon_{t-1}\varepsilon_{t-1}\right]+\rho E\left[v_{t}y_{t-2}\right]+\phi E\left[v_{t}\varepsilon_{t}\right]$

$E\left[\varepsilon_{t}y_{t-1}\right]=\phi E\left[\varepsilon_{t-1}^{2}\right]>0$

It should be clear that since $E\left[\varepsilon_{t}y_{t-1}\right]\neq0$ the OLS estimator, $\hat{\rho}_{OLS}$, will not be consistent.